# isPostback always returns false, even after posting back to the page

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net page and on the page is a select box. When someone changes the selected item in the select box, some fancy javascript fires to put the selected value into a hidden form at the bottom of the page and submit that value back to the page.

```
<script>
 function cat(inForm){
        document.getElementById('Cat_ID').value = inForm.Catechumen_ID.value;
        document.getElementById('passCat').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Based upon this postback, I want to update the page to be based upon the value that was posted back to the page.

I added:

```
<script>

    alert("postback: <%= Page.IsPostBack = true %>" );
</script>
```

to the page and it alerts me that isPostback is false on initial load and after postback. why?

Comment: The Javascript has been added.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it, why ask if isPostBack = true, when I can simply ask if the variable I posted has a value.

```
if request.form("cat_ID") <> "" then
  'isPostBack
else
  'not isPostBack
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

You normally use 'is post back' page property in page load event for data bindings for controls such as grid view that use view state.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

   If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

    ' More coding will go here.
    '--------------------------
   End If
```

Comment: Where would I find that code if I had it? Would it be at the top of the page before the <!doctype> tag?

Comment: If you want to embed vb.net code inside aspx  file you should follow the rules like the following page :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178135(v=vs.140)

Comment: I have always used embedded code blocks. That's how I've been doing things since back in the ASP days :-)